# How to focus on Electron window when it opens after focussing on another program

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm creating an Electron app that should show itself when a global shortcut key is pressed. For the shortcut key, I'm using iohook and that part works well.
If I allow the window to be shown as normally during startup of the app, Windows focusses on it (my test is pressing alt to see which menu bar is activated).

The problem is that if I start the program with `visible: false` or do not generate the `Electron.BrowserWindow` yet, and then call `win.show()` or create the window when I press the shortcut key, it opens the window in the foreground but the focus is still on the app that I was on before pressing the shortcut.

I have fixed this in the past with Autohotkey but I want to make this app cross-platorm and preferably contain as much of my code as possible within NodeJS.

Comment: Have you tried using `win.focus()` instead or as well as `win.show()`?

Comment: I did, yes but it didn't do anything. I just though of adding a delay before calling focus and that works. I guess there's a delay in the OS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out there is a delay in the OS before the window can be focussed on. Calling `focus()` immediately after `show()` does nothing (or may in some cases if it wins the race conditions). Using the `show` event to trigger the focus solves this.

```
win.on('show', () => { win.focus(); });
win.show();
```

EDIT: There still seems to be a race condition on the OS level that sometimes causes the window not to be focussed so I still have to add the timeout:

```
win.on('show', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    win.focus();
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: why not `win.on('shown', () => { win.focus() }); win.show();`, then?

Comment: Seems the event is `show`, not `shown` but that is definitely a better solution, taking away the question of how long the timeout should be. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Correction: it doesn't always work. There is still a race condition on the OS level