# How to flash messages (or pop-ups) on desktop screen at regular intervals

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application

I'm trying to make an app that reminds me to blink by presenting a small blinking animation in the middle of the screen every 15 seconds regardless of what I have open (I have dry eye and don't blink enough when I'm on the computer). I already have a similar app installed on my phone but couldn't find one for desktop, so I resolved to make one. I'm using Windows 10.

I've tried using Electron but so far can only find apis to make the regular Windows notifications that appear on the bottom right.

I have downloaded an app called EyeLeo that does something similar to what I'm trying to achieve, so I know it must be possible, though it only flashes messages every 5 minutes (image below)

Anybody got any ideas?

edit:
I can't use the alert box because it's quite large and obstructive and doesn't disappear on it's own as far as I know In terms of just flashing an html element on the screen (aka a custom alert) I'm not sure how to make it so it appears over whatever I have open. For instance if I have my browser open and the app in the background, how do I make the element appear over my browser window? That's the difficulty

[image]

Comment: Update: apparently there might be a solution in creating a new window in electron that appears over the top of over windows. Going to learn more and give it a shot and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Electronjs with a timeout and an interval, like this

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 220,
    frame: false,
    show: false
  })

  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    setInterval(() => win.show(), 15000) // 15s for show
  })

  win.on('show', () => {
    setTimeout(() => win.hide(), 3000) // 3s for hide
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
})
```

Comment: It takes some time for the window to appear focused (3 seconds work for me)  ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60314425/13002218))

Answer (score 1):

You can set an **asynchronous interval** for this:

```
// Define the notification function : 
function blink() {
  // Either add an html message in your page or just alert a message
  // alert("Blink");

  // Create a div for the blink-message (with absolute position at top)
  var alertBox = document.createElement('div');
  alertBox.innerText = "Reminder: Please Blink";
  alertBox.style.zIndex = "99999";
  alertBox.style.position = "fixed";
  alertBox.style.width = "100%";
  alertBox.style.top = "0px";
  //alertBox.style.left = "1%";
  alertBox.style.padding = "5px";
  alertBox.style.background = "#242424";
  alertBox.style.color = "white";
  alertBox.style.border = "1px solid white";
  alertBox.style.boxShadow = "5px 5px 5px 5px rgb(0,0,0,0.2)";
  
  // Append this div to the document body
  document.body.appendChild(alertBox);

  // Remove the notification msg after 2 sec
  setTimeout( function(){ document.body.removeChild(alertBox); }, 2000);
}
```

```
// Set an interval to alert every 10 seconds:
var blinkInterval = setInterval( blink, 10000);
```

```
// To unset the interval, use clearInterval : 
clearInterval(blinkInterval);
```

Comment: I can't use the alert box because it's quite large and obstructive and doesn't disappear on it's own as far as I know
In terms of just flashing an html element on the screen (aka a custom alert) I'm not sure how to make it so it appears over whatever I have open. For instance if I have my browser open and the app in the background, how do I make the element appear over my browser window?  That's the difficulty

Comment: You can check the updated blink function. I've added code for custom notification